# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word - get out focus of OLEObject(ClassType: "Excel.Sheet.12")

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm creating an "integrated" Excel Sheet on Word (using Word, the one that you can create through Insert > Table > Excel Sheet), using this code :

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

...

Word.Application wapp = new Word.Application();

...

wapp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType: "Excel.Sheet.12"); // inserting on a Selection is on purpose
```

Once this Table is created, it automatically "opens" / takes focus. I have no problem to create other Word object (paragraphs / checkboxes ...) after that, but I still haven't succeeded losing this focus. It is not a big issue but it's just anoying in a UX point of vue ;)

Manually, what I call "losing focus", would be like a click somewhere on the Word page but out out the Excel Table, that bring back the focus on the Word page. Pushing the "Escape" button also work manually.

Any suggestions how to do it programatically ?

Comment: I can only suggest; the Word API exposes the ability to change the selected text - possibly using that API will cause focus to change.

Comment: In fact, I'm writing things afterwards that "table" but the Excel document is still "open". Somehow, the fact to write/[select + write] after it doesn't change anything :/